# Stopping an App From Installing

Tags: android, installation, sleep

I'm looking for a way to stop the installation of an Android app. Something to make it sleep or prevent it from installing after it is downloaded. Basically, i'm trying to find a way to do this so another program I have can check is for malware. Is there anything within the Android system that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anything within the Android system that can do this?

Fortunately, no, for obvious security reasons. You are welcome to create your own ROM mod containing a revised version of Android that contains your code, integrated into the package-installation process.